# Ubuntu 13.10 can't satisfy dependency libpackagekit-glib2-14

Tags: linux, ubuntu, graphics, intel, drivers

I've just installed Ubuntu 13.10 on my laptop, not as an upgrade but as a clean install.

Everything is working great, except for the fact that I'm now attempting to install the Intel graphics drivers from [the official page](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2013/intelr-linux-graphics-installer-version-1.0.2) and have run into a dependency error.

The package is asking for **libpackagekit-glib2-*14*** and failing for lack of inclusion in the repos (as far as I can tell). I do have **libpackagekit-glib2-*16*** installed, but as far as I can tell there is no way to revert back to 14, or install alongside.

If anyone could give me some guidance on a resolution to this I'd be greatly appreciative.

Comment: Note: if you came from the Ubuntu bug tracker this place does not work the same. Don't add "Thanks", unrelated problems, or anything that isn't an answer in the answer box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is a bit old now but there is no awnser, so, here we go...
There is a new version, Intel(R) Graphics Installer 1.0.3 for Linux, that supports libpackagekit-glib2-16.

https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2013/intelr-graphics-installer-1.0.3-linux

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! I've been checking on a fairly regular basis waiting for it to come out.

Answer (score 0):

First try with

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f
```

If it doesn't work & the error still persist,
simply remove the old library as

```
$ sudo apt-get remove libpackagekit-glib2-16
OR
$ sudo dpkg -r libpackagekit-glib2-16
```

Whichever works for you.

Then freshly install your package. If the error about dependancy still persist, install the required library with following command.

```
$ sudo dpkg -i libpackagekit-glib2-14
OR 
$ sudo apt-get install libpackagekit-glib2-16
```

Finally you can remove the dependancies with the first command provided in this answer.

Comment: I thought I should add on here for anyone else looking that removing libpackagekit-glib2-16 also attempts to remove basically the entire DE, and is not a feasible solution. I still have not found a way around this and am waiting for a release which uses libpackagekit-glib2-16.